# New line From text file to columns in csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am kind of new to programming soo please bear with me.

I have a `.txt` file and I'm reading it. The file contains elements in the following format:

- **Name**: *name_1*
- **Error Text**: *some_text_1*
- **Correct Text**: *some_text_2*
- **Type of Error**: *some_text_3*

This format is repeated allways.

I want to write this file to **csv** which will have columns (the elements mentioned before) and be like:

| Name | Error Text | Correct Text | Type of Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *name_1* | *some_text_1* | *some_text_2* | *some_text_3* |

```
with open(filename) as infile, open('outfile.csv','w') as outfile:  
    for line in infile: 
        outfile.write(line)
```

This is all i could come up with, code just wrote down text to csv.

Comment: Your code will just copy the contents of infile to outfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a csv file from text and have columns then can use `csv.DictWriter` to create columns

```
import csv

# Set fieldnames for the CSV file
fieldnames = ['Name', 'Error Text', 'Correct Text', 'Type of Error']

# convert data to dictionaries 
rows = []

with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):  # Process four lines at a time
        name = lines[i].split(":")[1].strip()
        error_text = lines[i + 1].split(":")[1].strip()
        correct_text = lines[i + 2].split(":")[1].strip()
        type_of_error = lines[i + 3].split(":")[1].strip()
        rows.append({'Name': name, 'Error Text': error_text, 'Correct Text': correct_text, 'Type of Error': type_of_error})

# Write CSV file
with open('yourfileoutput.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the input file line by line. Split on colon. Check that the keyword is in sequence. Build a dictionary of the input data.

Open an output file (CSV) and dump the column headers and dictionary contents as follows:

```
from itertools import cycle

COLUMNS = ['Name', 'Error Text', 'Correct Text', 'Type of Error']
TXTFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/input.txt'
CSVFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/output.csv'
SEP = '|'

d = {}

column = cycle(COLUMNS)

with open(TXTFILE) as indata:
    for line in indata:
        k, v = line.split(':')
        if k == next(column):
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(v.strip())
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Unexpected keyword "{k}"')

with open(CSVFILE, 'w') as outdata:
    print(SEP.join(COLUMNS), file=outdata)
    for data in zip(*d.values()):
        print(SEP.join(data), file=outdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input file:

```
Name: name_1
Error Text: some_text_1_1
Correct Text: some_text_1_2
Type of Error: some_text_1_3
Name: name_2
Error Text: some_text_2_1
Correct Text: some_text_2_2
Type of Error: some_text_2_3
Name: name_3
Error Text: some_text_3_1
Correct Text: some_text_3_2
Type of Error: some_text_3_3
```

Just use pure pandas with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and `': '` as separator, then [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a de-duplicating column based on groups restarting with each "Name" (with help of [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)), finally [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), and export [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = (pd.read_csv(filename, sep=r':\s+', engine='python', header=None)
        .assign(idx=lambda d: d[0].eq('Name').cumsum())
        .pivot(index='idx', columns=0, values=1)
     )
df.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)
```

Output file:

```
Correct Text,Error Text,Name,Type of Error
some_text_1_2,some_text_1_1,name_1,some_text_1_3
some_text_2_2,some_text_2_1,name_2,some_text_2_3
some_text_3_2,some_text_3_1,name_3,some_text_3_3
```

To keep the original order of the columns:

```
df = (pd.read_csv(filename, sep=r':\s+', engine='python', header=None)
        .assign(idx=lambda d: d[0].eq('Name').cumsum())
        .pipe(lambda d: d.pivot(index='idx', columns=0, values=1)[d[0].unique()])
     )
df.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
Name,Error Text,Correct Text,Type of Error
name_1,some_text_1_1,some_text_1_2,some_text_1_3
name_2,some_text_2_1,some_text_2_2,some_text_2_3
name_3,some_text_3_1,some_text_3_2,some_text_3_3
```

Comment: How can this be modified such that the CSV column names are in the same order as in the input file?

Comment: @DarkKnight you can reorder with the unique names (unique keeps the original order). See update ;)